Avoid duplication in lists of terraform variables (Google Cloud Run)
I have a list of environment variables I want to make available for Google Cloud Run instances (1 service, 4 jobs)
Environment variables are shared massively between these jobs and if I need to add/change/remove any of them I need to do it 5 times, obviously this creates opportunities for errors to creep in, and I'm repeating myself a lot.
I thought of having a variable that contained all of these values and then unpacked them into the containers section of the terraform declaration.
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_job" "example_cloud_run_job" {
  # project, location, name, dependency info in here
  template {
    # template info such as parallelism and task count here
    template {
      # more info in here
      containers {
        # image, networking info, resources in here, but also a lot of environment variables!
        env {
          name  = "foo"
          value = var.bar
        }
        env {
          name  = "baz"
          value = var.qux
        }
        env {
          name  = "quux"
          value = var.corge
        }
        env {
          name  = "grault"
          value = var.garply
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I'm hoping there is something I can do to unpack these variables into the containers object, similarly to how we could do it in JavaScript/Typescript with the ... operator or with the * operator in Python. I can't find this in the documentation for Terraform and I am sure that I am not the first to come across this problem!
I have been reading through the documentation and playing around in the code a bit but not come across a solid approach for this.

There is similarly an operator in HCL2 TF to convert into a tuple (and it is also ...), but it is unclear how that relates to the problem you are attempting to solve here. Please demonstrate it with an example input and a desired result.

What you could do is use for_each meta-argument in combination with dynamic. You would also need to create a variable which will be used to iterate over:
variable "env_vars" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Map of environment variables."

  default = {
    foo    = "some value"
    baz    = "some value"
    quux   = "some value"
    grault = "some value"
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_v2_job" "example_cloud_run_job" {
  # project, location, name, dependency info in here
  template {
    # template info such as parallelism and task count here
    template {
      # more info in here
      containers {
        dynamic "env" {
          for_each = var.env_vars
          content {
            name  = env.key
            value = env.value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


This definitely seems like it is answering the true question above. The current question content implies that the type may currently be list(map(string)) in which case that should be converted to map(string) as shown in this answer for efficiency.

This is working an absolute treat for me on the simpler ones! I have also adapted it for when we are getting environment variables from secrets - I'll accept and update the answer
